# Visual Studio 2013 and ASPX view engine

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

We have a VS 2010, MVC 2, ASP.Net 4.0 and ASPX view engine project that we need to upgrade. I have installed the below version of the VS 2013. I am not seeing an aspx engine option when i click on new website. Am i missing something here?

I wanted to create a webproject and then copy paste the items from the old project to new rather than dealing with upgrade issues like on our MVC 3/Razor project upgrade couple of weeks back.

**Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013
Version 12.0.21005.1 REL
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.50938**

Installed Version: Professional

LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2013   06177-004-0444002-02646
Microsoft LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2013

Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2013 ENU   06177-004-0444002-02646
Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2013 ENU

Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2013   06177-004-0444002-02646
Microsoft Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2013

Visual Basic 2013   06177-004-0444002-02646
Microsoft Visual Basic 2013

Visual C# 2013   06177-004-0444002-02646
Microsoft Visual C# 2013

Visual C++ 2013   06177-004-0444002-02646
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013

Visual F# 2013   06177-004-0444002-02646
Microsoft Visual F# 2013

Visual Studio 2013 Code Analysis Spell Checker   06177-004-0444002-02646
Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2013 Code Analysis Spell Checker

Portions of International CorrectSpell™ spelling correction system © 1993 by Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights reserved.

The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Third Edition Copyright © 1992 Houghton Mifflin Company. Electronic version licensed from Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights reserved.

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.21001.0
For additional information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309563

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.0.11001.0
For additional information, visit http://www.asp.net/

Common Azure Tools   1.0
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Windows Azure Tools.

Adds visual guides at each indentation level.

Microsoft Web Developer Tools 2013   2.0.40926.0
Microsoft Web Developer Tools contains the following components:
Support for creating and opening ASP.NET web projects
Browser Link: A communication channel between Visual Studio and browsers
Editor extensions for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript
Page Inspector: Inspection tool for ASP.NET web projects
Scaffolding: A framework for building and running code generators
Server Explorer extensions for Windows Azure Web Sites
Web publishing: Extensions for publishing ASP.NET web projects to hosting providers, on-premises servers, or Windows Azure

Windows Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.0
Windows Azure Mobile Services Tools

Workflow Manager Tools 1.0   1.0
This package contains the necessary Visual Studio integration components for Workflow Manager.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it is not supported as of yet, but MS is planning on adding the support in a future release.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/27/html-editing-features-in-visual-studio-2013-preview.aspx

I had to look this up the other day for the exact same reasons as you, however, we are converting our views to razor at the same time, so impact was minimal on our end.

Comment: Can i open the project in VS2013 and will it work without any issues -- aspx engine wise? I'll take care of the rest of the problems.

Comment: Yes, you can edit the files in VS2013, however you will not have any intellisense.  It will be like working in notepad essentially.

Answer (score 0):

WebFormViewEngine is installed by default. just check out the `ViewEngines.Engines` collection. Its output are:

- System.Web.Mvc.WebFormViewEngine
- System.Web.Mvc.RazorViewEngine